# Using double quotes in awk

Tags: linux, shell

This command will print `a`.

```
echo "line1 a b c" | awk '{ print $2 }'
```

If I change single quotes to double quotes, like this, it will print whole line.

```
echo "line1 a b c" | awk "{ print $2 }"
```

Why? I know I should use single quotes, but why is the whole line printed if I use double quotes?

Comment: With double quotes, the shell expands `$2` to the second positional parameter, which might very well be empty, and awk only sees `print`.

Comment: @BenjaminW. Agree with your answer, but don't think it is duplicate.

Comment: I can't see how it *isn't* duplicative. An answer to how single quotes and double quotes are different in bash answers how they're different when using bash to call `awk`, because the sole difference is the shell's behavior; `awk` has no way of telling the difference between `awk '{ print  }'` and `awk "{ print $2 }"` with bash having an empty `$2`.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If the `awk` command is single quoted, the `$2` is not interpreted by the shell, but is instead passed as the literal string `$2` to `awk`. `awk` will then `print` the second space delimited token in the input string, which in this case is `a`.

```
echo "line1 a b c" | awk '{ print $2 }' # prints the second space-delimited token
> a
```

If the `awk` command is double quoted, the `$2` is interpreted by the shell. Because `$2` is empty (in this case), the empty string is substituted. `awk` sees a command which looks like `awk "{ print }"`, which is an instruction to print everything.

```
echo "line1 a b c" | awk '{ print }' # prints all input
> line1 a b c
```

It is also possible to use double qotes, and escape the `$`, which will cause the `$` to not be interpreted by the shell, and instead the `$2` string will be passed to `awk`.

```
echo "line1 a b c" | awk "{ print \$2 }" # prints the second space-delimited token
> a
```